# Linq query to Parse XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the XML shown below. I am trying to parse using C# with LINQ.

```
<software>
    <version>31.0.1</version>
    <status>uptime 2d 22h 39m 26s</status>
    <wPack>
        <rv>
            <total>0</total>
            <qv>0</qv>
        </rv>
        <sv>
            <total>0</total>
            <qv>0</qv>
        </sv>
    </wPack>
    <sPack>
        <rv>
            <total>242</total>
            <qv>1</qv>
        </rv>
        <sv>
            <total>69845</total>
            <qv>145</qv>
        </sv>
        <size>146</size>
    </sPack>
    <dPack>
        <rv>
            <total>88560</total>
        </rv>
        <sv>
            <total>0</total>
        </sv>
        <in>0.28,0.23,0.35</in>
        <out>0.00,0.00,0.00</out>
        <qv>216806</qv>
        <db>mysql</db>
    </dPack>
    <bClients>
        <bClient>
            <type>sPackbClient</type>
            <id>test1</id>
            <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
            <queue>0</queue>
            <status>on-line 2d 22h 39m 21s</status>
            <ssl>no</ssl>
        </bClient>
        <bClient>
            <type>sPackbClient</type>
            <id>test2</id>
            <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
            <queue>0</queue>
            <status>on-line 2d 22h 39m 18s</status>
            <ssl>no</ssl>
        </bClient>
        <bClient>
            <type>sPackbClient</type>
            <id>test3</id>
            <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
            <queue>0</queue>
            <status>on-line 0d 2h 33m 30s</status>
            <ssl>no</ssl>
        </bClient>
    </bClients>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <name>EC1</name>
            <admin-id>EC1</admin-id>
            <id>EC1</id>
            <status>online 8901s</status>
            <failed>0</failed>
            <qv>0</qv>
            <sPack>
                <rv>0</rv>
                <sv>0</sv>
                <in>0.00,0.00,0.00</in>
                <out>0.00,0.00,0.00</out>
            </sPack>
            <dPack>
                <rv>0</rv>
                <sv>0</sv>
                <in>0.00,0.00,0.00</in>
                <out>0.00,0.00,0.00</out>
            </dPack>
        </server>
        <server>
            <name>EC2</name>
            <admin-id>EC2</admin-id>
            <id>EC2</id>
            <status>online 8918s</status>
            <failed>2</failed>
            <qv>0</qv>
            <sPack>
                <rv>79</rv>
                <sv>20843</sv>
                <in>0.00,0.00,0.00</in>
                <out>0.06,0.05,0.08</out>
            </sPack>
            <dPack>
                <rv>35050</rv>
                <sv>0</sv>
                <in>0.10,0.07,0.14</in>
                <out>0.00,0.00,0.00</out>
            </dPack>
        </server>
        <server>
            <name>EC3</name>
            <admin-id>EC3</admin-id>
            <id>EC3</id>
            <status>re-connecting</status>
            <failed>0</failed>
            <qv>0</qv>
            <sPack>
                <rv>4</rv>
                <sv>1671</sv>
                <in>0.00,0.00,0.00</in>
                <out>0.00,0.00,0.00</out>
            </sPack>
            <dPack>
                <rv>1664</rv>
                <sv>0</sv>
                <in>0.00,0.00,0.00</in>
                <out>0.00,0.00,0.00</out>
            </dPack>
        </server>
    </servers>
</software>
```

When I try to get `<sPack>` elements using following query.

```
var software = (from sw in xDoc.Descendants("software")
                from sp in sw.Descendants("sPack")
                select sp).ToList();
```

I get all instance of `<sPack>` which are under:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <sPack>
```

What i want is to get `<sPack>` which comes under `<software>` and a separate query for parsing `<servers>`.

Comment: You might consider XPath instead. It's as easy as selectNodes( "/servers/servers/server/sPack " )

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use `xDoc.Root.Elements("sPack")` to select the `sPack` child element(s) of the root element and then `xDoc.Root.Elements("servers").Elements("server").Elements("sPack")` to select the `sPack` descendants of the `server` element(s).

Answer (score 0):

The `sPack` element you're getting as part of your query *is a descendant* of`software`. As `software` is the root element, all elements within are descendants. The example [in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) shows how this query works.

What you want is [`Elements`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975(v=vs.110).aspx), which only returns the *child* elements, it doesn't involve any recursion.

```
var software = xDoc.Elements("software").Elements("sPack");
```

For your second query, you *do* want to search recursively through all elements. So `Descendants` is appropriate here:

```
var servers = xDoc.Descendants("servers").Descendants("sPack");
```